# dynamic form struts

Tags: forms, dynamic, struts

I'm new at Struts 1.3.

I need to invite some people to a poll that has been sent and they have not answered. I have gathered these people in a table with a column with a checkbox to invite them again to the poll. This column has dynamic fields with struts tag form field indexed. (You can't invite people that have answered again)

JSP view:

```
    <logic:iterate id="respondent" collection="${respondent}">

    <logic:notEqual name="respondent" property="participation" value="true">
            <html:checkbox indexed="true" property="participation" name="respondent" value="true"></html:checkbox>
    </logic:notEqual>

    </logic:iterate>
```

Form:

```
public class F_Invite extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

public F_Invite() {
    super();
}

private Map<String, String> respondent = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void setRespondent(String key, String value) {
    respondent.put(key, value);
}

public void setRespondent(Map<String, String> nut) {
    this.encuestado = nut;
}

public Map<String, String> getRespondent(){
    return this.encuestado;
}

public String getRespondent(String key) {
    return encuestado.get(key);
}

public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {

    respondent.clear();

}
```

I get a NullPointerException when in the action I do this:

```
    F_Invite nonparticipants = (F_Invite) form;

    Map<String, String> participantstoinvite = nonparticipants.getRespondent();

    Iterator iter = participantstoinvite.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry entrada = (Map.Entry) iter.next();            

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct, as all the details are not in the question here, I would suggest you to change

`<logic:iterate id="respondent" collection="${respondent}">' to
'<logic:iterate **name**="respondent" collection="${respondent}">`

The requirement you have is not clear from your question, have a feeling english is not your first language :)